# Change serialized property name in Symfony serialisation

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony serializer. It works well.

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * 
 * @Groups({"default", "notification"})
 */
public function getUser()
{
    ...
}
```

Is it possible serialise property as another name?
So I want to use `getUser` in framework, but property should named as `profile` in serialised json.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit 19-11-2018**, this feature is now available since Symfony 4.2:

```
/**
 * @SerializedName("some_name")
 */
private $lastName;
```

More information in the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/master/components/serializer.html#configure-name-conversion-using-metadata).

Thanks to [Sodj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842244/change-serialized-property-name-in-symfony-serialisation/47844051#comment93600026_47844051) for the reminder.

---

You can use a custom name converter for that purpose. Every information to achieve this are in [this part](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#name-converter) of the doc.

There is also an issue opened to override property name of the serialized object directly with annotations https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15171

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to inspect it.

Comment: Ok. So Symfony serialise not contain @SerializedName feature. So I need to override rules for converter. It's not comfortably

Comment: Now you can use `serialized_name` in model serialize config

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried, like for JMSserializer, this annotation :
@SerializedName("changed_name") -  https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#serializedname ?

Comment: I'm tried it before as `@Serializer\SerializedName("foo")` but it's not works. btw, I forgot mention symfony version. I'm using 3.4

Comment: Symfony serialiser not contain @SerializedName feature.