# symfony deserialize into object with different keys

Tags: php, json, symfony, deserialization, jsonserializer

From an API I get a output like that:

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "code": "string",
  "addInfo2": "",
  "addInfo3": "23536723462",
  "addInfo4": null,
  "addInfo5": null,
  "arrow": "none",
  "IdList": [
    "2357789234"
  ],
  "templateName": null,
  "rotationDegrees": "0"
}
```

Now I want to deserialize this jsonstring into an Object by calling:

> $this->serializer->deserialize($jsonLabelMappings, LabelMappings::class, 'json');

But I want that the Object has other keys/attributenames. My object should look like that:

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "code": "string",
  "originCountry": "", /* this is the addInfo2 */
  "gtin": "23536723462", /* this is the ddInfo3 */
  "wildfang": null, /* this is the addInfo4 */
  "arrow": "none",
  "ids": [ /* this is the articleIdList */
    "2357789234"
  ],
  "templateName": null,
  "rotationDegrees": "0"
}
```

Is there any anotation like @Serializer\DeserializeName or something? Or how can I tell my code that the keyName from the json is something other?

Comment: Should be easy to do by turning the json into an array. Loop through the array and replace the key with the new one. That's what I would do.

Comment: If this is backed by an Entity or DTO or similar, you might be able to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47844051/231316

Comment: This may also be of interest: [Converting property names while serializing or deserializing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#converting-property-names-when-serializing-and-deserializing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I didn't get any answer which woul solve my problem with annotations or something "short". I now did it with @Fly_Moe answer:

Should be easy to do by turning the json into an array. Loop through the array and replace the key with the new one. That's what I would do

Answer (score 0):

There is SerializedName attribute (or annotation) for the exact use case.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#configure-name-conversion-using-metadata

Alternatively you can use SerializedPath attribute

https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-nested-attributes